# node.js server can't receive any calls unless an empty folder is created on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm probably doing something silly, and putting myself in a situation that I don't need to be in. But my ultimate question is why do I have to have an empty folder in my server in order for my GET requests to work?

Before I start with an example, everything is under a subfolder: http://www.example.org/subfolder1

Here is Server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const datastore = require('nedb');

const url = require("url");
var path = require('path');
const app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server, 
{   
    path: '/subfolder1/socket.io',
    cors: 
    {
        origin: '*',
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        credentials: true
    }
});
const port = 3000;

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log("Socket connected: " + socket.id);
});

app.get("/subfolder1/getSettings", (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({ configuration: conf });
});

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/subfolder1/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

server.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', function(error){
if(error) {
    console.log('Server failed to listen: ', error)
} else{
    console.log('Server is listening on port: ' + port)
}
```

});

client code:

```
const response = await fetch("/subfolder1/getSettings");
const settings = await response.json();
```

Now, in this example I'm calling getSettings (http://www.example.org/subfolder1/getSettings):

```
app.get("/subfolder1/getSettings", (req, res, next) => {
   res.json({ configuration: conf });
});
```

No matter what I do, I will forever get a 404 error message unless I create an empty folder called "getSettings" in my folder structure on my server. Once I create the empty folder, the call works! So for now, I've just making empty folders on my server for my get calls. Well now look what happens when the URL is something more complicated, such as the following:

http://www.example.org/subfolder1/team=6/queuedPlayers (Where team can be any integer)

Now I'm stuck and my workaround is broken. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, Express by itself, does not require ANY folders exist that correspond to any of your routes so something you are doing in your server configuration or your server code must be causing this issue, but since you don't show us any of the relevant configuration or code, there's really not much we can do to help.  Show us everything that is relevant and maybe folks here could help.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: FYI, `http://www.example.org/subfolder1/team=6/queuedPlayers` is not typically how you would design a variable URL.  More typical would be one of these: `http://www.example.org/subfolder1/team/6/queuedPlayers` or `http://www.example.org/subfolder1/queuedPlayers?team=6`.

Comment: Added my server and client code as well.

Comment: What folder has to be created for what URL to work?

Comment: getSettings. Under my public_html, I have the folder subfolder1. But it isn't until I create a folder under subfolder1 called getSettings will things work.

Comment: The only code you show that has anything to do with folders on your server is the `express.static()` middleware, but that does not come into play on `await fetch("/subfolder1/getSettings");` unless you have some proxy in front of your server that is further manipulating the path before it gets to your server.  So, that is my guess.  There's some other infrastructure messing with things.

Comment: Add this middleware as the first route in your server: `app.use((req, res, next) => {console.log("incoming path: ", req.path); next();});` and see what it logs when things are not working.

Comment: Added, and ran. Just trying to figure out how to read server logs using godaddy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235922/discussion-between-jsirr13-and-jfriend00).